# Polymer paper-input doesn't seem to properly block decimal points via allowed-pattern when type is set to number

Tags: android, input, keyboard, polymer, decimal

I'm using a paper-input with type="number". I'd like this input to be an integer and therefore only accept digit characters. As such, I've set the allowed-pattern to [0-9]. When the input gains focus on my tablet, a numeric keyboard appears, which is perfect. That keyboard, however, has a decimal point button, and if I click it, the decimal point is allowed. What's worse is that if another digit is chosen after the decimal point, the entire input value gets wiped out.

What's odd to me is that if I change the input type from "number" to "text", it behaves correctly. The full alpha-numeric keyboard appears, but only digits can be typed. Even the decimal point is correctly blocked and cannot be typed. This is the behavior I want, but I don't want the alphanumeric keyboard to appear. I'd prefer the numeric keyboard.

Is there something I can do to block the decimal point character when the input's type is set to "number"?

Here's a code example. On my tablet, the first input (type="number") accepts a decimal point. The second input (type="text") does not. Ideally, I want the behavior of the second input, but the numeric keyboard of the first input.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>

<body style="background:white">
    <paper-input type="number" allowed-pattern="[0-9]" label="Does not block decimal point"></paper-input>
    <paper-input type="text" allowed-pattern="[0-9]" label="Correctly blocks decimal point"></paper-input>
</body>
</html>
```

In case it helps/matters, I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4. I haven't tried it on other devices. I'm also using Cordova to convert the code to an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way that the native `input` element with `type="number"` handles input. If you type anything that is not a correct number, for example anything with a trailing decimal `1.`, it will return an empty value (`""` instead of `"1."`). Now, `paper-input` is implemented to check the value when it changes and reset the input to the last correct value when it encounters an incorrect value. However, the empty value is a correct input, so it will do nothing. The same behaviour also causes this [issue on Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/264#issuecomment-176489037).

I don't think there is much you can do. If you want the number pad, you won't be able to prevent the decimal as the user types. You could clean the input after it has been entered.